# Deducting travel costs for summer internship on J-1 visa

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, travel

I am a full-time PhD student at a university in Germany. To get funding for my PhD studies, I am employed as a research assistant by the university (I have been continuously employed in this position since 2013). In 2016, I was in the U.S. for a 12-weeks long (paid) internship on a J-1 visa.

Can the internship be considered to be a "Temporary Assignment or Job" (as per IRS Publication 463), or a "Work-Related Education" (IRS Publication 970) so that I would be able to deduct the travel expenses I had for the internship?